# Swift SpriteKit - Sprite vs Other Graphics

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

Is there a different graphics file format like a vector / 3d graphics model that is used in 2D games for ease of rotation?

In the past, I would use a set of sprites that have 8 direction animation for character walking.  Is there a better way to animate a character walking using 1 character file format?  Not sure if I am asking the right question.

I figured that a 3D model can be rotated to the direction the character is walking to reduce the need for additional sprites.

What do games like RPG, Evony use for sprite animation?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking,  but the only way to rotate a single sprite is if you have a topdown view of the sprite.  There is no way to create 3d models in a 2d world.  The only thing you may be able to do is snapshot the 3d model in each direction it is facing to give the illusion of rotation

Comment: maybe that is what I need is a top down view of a sprite.  I am not sure what I am asking. I guess what I am asking is if there is a common method to animate characters in all directions without having a spite set for all directions.  If a character can walk in all directions, what is a common way to set this up.  One way is to use a topdown view sprite. or a set of sprites that contains all direction. What would be another way?

Comment: What do the common RPG games use for their character animations?  A sprite sheet? games like Evony, Clash of Klans etc

Comment: no idea, never played those games.  They could be using a 3D environment, or they could have everything prerendered and snap shoted